# Cannot access mongoose model in a middleware declared as static

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have some routes for which I want to check the parameters. When doing this, everything works fine:

```
var User = require('../../models/user');
router.param('userId', existsMiddleware)
router.get('/users/:userId, doSomething);

function existsMiddleware(req, res, next, userId) {
    User
      .findById(userId)
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        var errObj = { status: 404, message: 'No user with that ID'};
        if (err) {
          res.status(errObj.status).json(errObj);
        } else {
          !!user ? next() : res.status(errObj.status).json(errObj);
        }
      });
}
```

I'd like to move it, for convenience as it is a shared library, to the the model `User` as a static method. The problem is that I cannot access the model (`this`) in this specific case.

Let's rephrase the routes file:

```
var User = require('../../models/user');
router.param('userId', User.existsMiddleware)
router.get('/users/:userId, doSomething);
```

And in my user *Schema* I have:

```
var user = mongoose.Schema(schemaObject);
user.statics.existsMiddleware = existsMiddleware;
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);

function existsMiddleware(req, res, next, userId) {
    this
      .findById(userId)
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        var errObj = { status: 404, message: 'No user with that ID'};
        if (err) {
          res.status(errObj.status).json(errObj);
        } else {
          !!user ? next() : res.status(errObj.status).json(errObj);
        }
      });
}
```

The problem is that when debugging, inside the function `existsMiddleware` evaluates to `undefined`, which is **not** happening for other static methods that I have and also employ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to bind the function to the model:

```
router.param('userId', User.existsMiddleware.bind(User))
```

Comment: That work indeed. Thanks a lot! I'm still wondering though why for this specific case, the object `User` is not already bound.